# How can I multiply n elements of a matrix by a number in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a matrix m and I want to have a user defined function which allows me to control the elements that are multiplied by a value.

The function `matrix:set-and-report` looks promising but I'm not sure how to implement this for multiple elements.

For example, I would like to multiply the first 3 elements of the matrix by -1 to move from this:

```
   let m matrix:from-row-list [1 2 3 4 5 6]
    print m
```

to this:

```
   let n matrix:from-row-list [-1 -2 -3 4 5 6]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `matrix:set-and-report` you were indeed pretty close to a solution. Please check the example, I hope this is what you were looking for. The report function has matrix as an input. Than you specify the row, than the index were you want to start the multiplication, where to end it, and finally the multiplier.

```
Extensions [
  matrix
]

to test
  let m matrix:from-row-list [ [1 2 3 4 5 6] [1 2 3 4 5 6] ]
  print (word "original matrix "  m)
  print (word "modified matrix "  matrix-row-manipulation m 0 0 3 -1)

end

to-report matrix-row-manipulation [matrix row columen-index-start columen-index-end multiplier]

  let index (range columen-index-start columen-index-end 1)

  foreach index [ i ->
    set matrix matrix:set-and-report matrix row i (matrix:get matrix row i * multiplier )

  ]

  report matrix


end
```

This will return you:

```
observer> test
original matrix {{matrix:  [ [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ][ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ] ]}}
modified matrix {{matrix:  [ [ -1 -2 -3 4 5 6 ][ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ] ]}}
```